# Reading file content using file name from db in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have to do a query in db to get the filenames from a table. And then I have to read the contents of files in a folder/directory using the file names I got from query. I have done the query part and stored the list of filenames in Exchange using a bean. But I am wondering how can I use this filenames in exchange to read the file contents. Could you please help?

Comment: I slightly expanded my answer..  hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pattern **Content Enricher**  (http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) and Camel 2.16 with dynamic endpoints to load the contents of a file, by path previously obtained from the database.

UPDATED

You have to use the **pollEnrich** (because **file** component is a **polling consumer**) to consume files from uri and you can use an expression (such as Simple) to configure the fileName.

You can try something like that (only for Camel version greater than 2.16):

```
.pollEnrich("file:?fileName=${header.FILE_NAME}", 1000, new YourAggregationStrategy())
```

Comment: I used pollEnrich and it worked as expected. Thanks a lot.